# No external video from Clevo computer running Debian 12

Tags: drivers, debian, graphics, nvidia, intel

I have a Clevo PD70SND-G, fresh from China. Installed Debian 12 Bookworm (dual boot with Windows 10 Pro). There is no video for the external monitor. Switching to Windows, I have verified it is not defective hardware. Debian detects both the Intel and NVIDIA video hardware and loads the drivers for the Intel hardware, but not the NVIDIA hardware. There appears to be a bug in the NVIDIA drivers that I am unable to overcome. Please help.

```
Info Center -> About this System:

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.5 KDE
Frameworks Version: 5.103.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.1.0-17-amd64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 32 × Intel® Core™ i9-14900HX
Memory: 62.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: Notebook
Product Name: > PD5x_7xSNC_SND_SNE
System Version: Not Applicable
```

```
$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          jvines@Clevo-Linux-Debian
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       -------------------------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: PD5x_7xSNC_SND_SNE
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 1 hour, 30 mins
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2798 (dpkg)
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.27.5
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin
  `Y$$                        Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3]
   `Y$$.                      Icons: [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3]
     `$$b.                    Terminal: konsole
       `Y$$b.                 CPU: Intel i9-14900HX (32) @ 2.200GHz
          `"Y$b._             GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile
              `"""            GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
                              Memory: 3546MiB / 64000MiB
```

```
$ inxi -Gxz
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-13 bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile]
    vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK driver: N/A arch: Lovelace bus-ID: 0000:01:00.0
  Device-3: Bison BisonCam NB Pro type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-8:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (RPL-S)
    direct-render: Yes

Sun Feb 11 - 16:21:17 > jvines > ~ >
 8/263/0 $ lspci | grep VGA
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics (rev 04)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] (rev a1)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f memory:76000000-76ffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:77080000-770fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff irq:206 memory:6204000000-6204ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Before installing driver: `$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver nvidia-detect nvidia-modprobe nvidia-settings`:

```
$ lsmod | grep -E "nouveau|nvidia"
nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight    16384  0
nouveau              2433024  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_display_helper    184320  2 i915,nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    94208  3 drm_ttm_helper,i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        204800  3 drm_display_helper,i915,nouveau
drm                   614400  36 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,drm_buddy,drm_ttm_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
video                  65536  3 nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,i915,nouveau
wmi                    36864  4 video,nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,mxm_wmi,nouveau
button                 24576  1 nouveau
```

After installing driver:

```
$ lsmod | grep -E "nouveau|nvidia"
nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight    16384  0
video                  65536  2 nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,i915
wmi                    36864  3 video,nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,mxm_wmi
```

```
$ nvidia-detect
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] [10de:28e0] (rev a1)

Checking card: 00.0 VGA compatible controller
Your card is supported by the default drivers and the Tesla driver series.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

```
$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


(nvidia-settings:8815): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:44:16.177: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:8815): CRITICAL **: 20:44:16.178: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed
```

Comment: You need to sign the unsigned proprietary Nvidia drivers so it works with Secure Boot: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Comment: And, indeed, ONLY with working Nvidia drivers -and- switching to the Nvidia profile you'll be able to use the external video ports because those are connected to the dGPU only. The Windows drivers toggle to that one seamlessly.